# Gui comunication with main thread

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class gui(threading.Thread, ):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        app = QApplication([])
        label = QLabel('Hello World!')
        l1 = QLabel('Moin servus')
        label.show()
        l1.show()
        while play:
            if edit:
                textedit(l1)
                False
        app.exec_()







if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = gui()
    t1.start()
    while play:
        textname = ("Willkommen beim legendären RPG!")
        edit = True
        wait()
        textname = ("Kurze Regeln man kann mit ja [j] oder nein [n] antworten")
        edit = True
        wait()
        textname = ("Viel Spaß Abenteurer")
        edit = True
        wait()
        textname = ("Bist du bereit?")
        edit = True
```

I would like to communicate with the gui thread how can i do this.
Because i am working on a rpg and i need to update the text in the gui in real time.

Comment: Did you intend to communicate using the ``edit`` variable? If so, the trailing ``False`` probably should have been ``edit = False``. Note that ``edit`` must be declared ``global edit`` if you want to modify it from inside a function/method.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you implement a class interface on your ui that allows you to do what you want: [**Tell, don't ask.**](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html)

Something like this:

```
class TextUI(threading.Thread):
    # __init__  and run as before

    def clear_screen(self):
        """Clear the text display area"""
        pass

    def writeln(self, *items):
        """Write items to next display line, then move down."""
        pass

    def write(self, *items):
        """Write items, leave cursor at end"""
        pass

    def cursor(self, state: CursorState):
        """Set state of cursor: on, blinking, off"""
        pass
```

Then you can rewrite your code to just *tell* the UI what you want to happen:

```
def game(tui: TextUI):
    """Play RPG repeatedly until player quits"""

    playing = True
    say = tui.writeln

    while playing:
        tui.clear_screen()
        say("Willkommen beim legendären RPG!")
        say("Kurze Regeln man kann mit ja [j] oder nein [n] antworten")
        say("Viel Spaß Abenteurer")
        say("Bist du bereit?")
```

Comment: This is not related to the question.